Limiting the depth of Boolean expressions
I am given a Boolean expression of arbitrary depth, like (A or (B and (C or (~D and E) or F) or (G and H))).  There can be any number of terms at each level.
I want to limit the depth of the expression (the maximum depth of nested parentheses + 1) to some constant like 4.  If the depth exceeds that bound, then I want to generate an equivalent expression with depth that does not exceed the bound.
I know that I can convert to CNF or DNF, which would limit the depth to 2, but the size of the expression can blow up exponentially.
How can I take advantage of more available levels to limit the size of the resulting expression as much as possible?

"but the size of the expression can blow up exponentially" - that'll still happen no matter what limit you choose.

How exactly do you measure the size that you want to minimise?

@Bergi The size I want to minimize would be the total number of terms.  I expect that it may still blow up exponentially, but maybe I can reduce the base?

Please poke me if I haven't tried this in a week or so. I don't promise a good attempt, but I do want to try. But life is, well, you know how it can be.

@btilly Good luck :D

@DevQt The origin of this problem is a bit esoteric.  It arises because I have to return a Boolean expression from a GraphQL server.  There are a few different ways to do it, but the "friendliest" way, returning it as a GraphQL object, requires establishing a maximum depth, because the GraphQL query language does not actually have the ability to request a structure of unbounded depth.  It's just a limitation of the language.  So the real-life possibility of expressions becoming large when depth is limited needs to be traded off against other ways of returning the object.

you can specify size to be 1. number of alphabets/variables including repretition, or 2. total terms in recursive manner, the exprn (a+b)(a+bc+d) will have terms 6 according to first,5 according to second,1 according to default meaning of term. just saying terms as mean of size will mean that CNF expressions are your solution with total terms=1 and depth=2

@redoc  by "term" I mean a conjunction, disjunction, or literal term (including negations).  It is a tree, not a DAG, so repeated terms count twice.

I still want to try, but life is worse than expected. Still my idea is that if you find something that would make sense with a depth s*k but you're only allowed to have k depth, you should aim to expand both ends to depth around k/2 and then let them both explode combinatorially as width makes up for the missing factor of 2s in the middle.

I don't know how far that gets you, or how good it will prove to be.
